# Is it possible to add several columns at once to a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

If I want to create a new DataFrame with several columns, I can add all the columns at once -- for example, as follows:

```
data = {'col_1': [0, 1, 2, 3],
        'col_2': [4, 5, 6, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

But now suppose farther down the road I want to add a set of additional columns to this DataFrame.  Is there a way to add them all simultaneously, as in

```
additional_data = {'col_3': [8, 9, 10, 11],
                   'col_4': [12, 13, 14, 15]}
#Below is a made-up function of the kind I desire.
df.add_data(additional_data)
```

I'm aware I could do this:

```
for key, value in additional_data.iteritems():
    df[key] = value
```

Or this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(additional_data, index=df.index)
df = pd.merge(df, df2, on=df.index)
```

I was just hoping for something cleaner.  If I'm stuck with these two options, which is preferred?

Comment: Tbh I think the for loop could be the best/most efficient way from a dict, although join feels "cleaner".

Comment: @AndyHayden may be it's possible to create new expand method. Can't say for sure, but if the number of columns is large, loop should be less efficient than one-time expand of array, or I'm wrong?

Comment: @RomanPekar if it's already a python object (a dict) I don't think it's going to get any faster. Hmmm have to test

Comment: This question seems very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050539/adding-multiple-columns-to-pandas-simultaneously

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pandas has [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) method since `0.16.0`. You could use it on dataframes like

```
In [1506]: df1.assign(**df2)
Out[1506]:
   col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
0      0      4      8     12
1      1      5      9     13
2      2      6     10     14
3      3      7     11     15
```

or, you could directly use the dictionary like

```
In [1507]: df1.assign(**additional_data)
Out[1507]:
   col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
0      0      4      8     12
1      1      5      9     13
2      2      6     10     14
3      3      7     11     15
```

Answer (score 10):

What you need is the `join` function:

```
df1.join(df2, how='outer')
#or
df1.join(df2) # this works also
```

Example:

```
data = {'col_1': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'col_2': [4, 5, 6, 7]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

additional_data = {'col_3': [8, 9, 10, 11],
               'col_4': [12, 13, 14, 15]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(additional_data)

df1.join(df2, how='outer')
```

output:

```
   col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
0      0      4      8     12
1      1      5      9     13
2      2      6     10     14
3      3      7     11     15
```

Comment: Ah, thanks!  But am I correct to infer there is no way to add `additional_data` to `df1` without first making a new DataFrame, `df2` (aside from the `for` loop option)?  It'd be nice to have `df1.add_data(additional_data)`.  I wonder whether Wes would be down for accepting such a submission to pandas.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to create new DataFrame from `additional_data`, you can use something like this:

```
>>> additional_data = [[8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
>>> df['col3'], df['col4'] = additional_data
>>> df
   col_1  col_2  col3  col4
0      0      4     8    12
1      1      5     9    13
2      2      6    10    14
3      3      7    11    15
```

It's also possible to do something like this, but it would be new DataFrame, not inplace modification of existing DataFrame:

```
>>> additional_header = ['col_3', 'col_4']
>>> additional_data = [[8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.concatenate((df.values.T, additional_data)).T, columns=np.concatenate((df.columns, additional_header)))
>>> df
   col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
0      0      4      8     12
1      1      5      9     13
2      2      6     10     14
3      3      7     11     15
```

Comment: Ah, good call.  But this option isn't so great when the number of new columns, and their names, can be variable.

Comment: @dbliss exactly, I'm thinking about is it possible to do this in general

Comment: @dbliss added another possible solution. Can't say I like it very much.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is create the new columns with data from the additional dataframe.

```
data =            {'col_1': [0, 1, 2, 3],
                   'col_2': [4, 5, 6, 7]}
additional_data = {'col_3': [8, 9, 10, 11],
                   'col_4': [12, 13, 14, 15]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(additional_data)

df[df2.columns] = df2
```

df now looks like:

```
   col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
0      0      4      8     12
1      1      5      9     13
2      2      6     10     14
3      3      7     11     15
```

Indices from the original dataframe will be used as if you had performed an in-place left join. Data from the original dataframe in columns with a matching name in the additional dataframe will be overwritten.
For example:

```
data =            {'col_1': [0, 1, 2, 3],
                   'col_2': [4, 5, 6, 7]}
additional_data = {'col_2': [8, 9, 10, 11],
                   'col_3': [12, 13, 14, 15]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(additional_data, index=[0,1,2,4])

df[df2.columns] = df2
```

df now looks like:

```
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0      0      8     12
1      1      9     13
2      2     10     14
3      3    NaN    NaN
```