# Add multiple columns to DataFrame and set them equal to an existing column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add multiple columns to a `pandas` `DataFrame` and set them equal to an existing column. Is there a simple way of doing this? In `R` I would do:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:5)
df[c('b','c')] <- df$a
df
  a b c
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5
```

In `pandas` this results in `KeyError: "['b' 'c'] not in index"`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(1,6)})
df[['b','c']] = df.a
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [.assign()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) method:

```
In [31]: df.assign(b=df['a'], c=df['a'])
Out[31]:
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
3  4  4  4
4  5  5  5
```

or a little bit more creative approach:

```
In [41]: cols = list('bcdefg')

In [42]: df.assign(**{col:df['a'] for col in cols})
Out[42]:
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
4  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
```

another solution:

```
In [60]: pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, len(cols)+1, axis=1), columns=['a']+cols)
Out[60]:
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
4  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
```

NOTE: as @Cpt_Jauchefuerst mentioned in the comment `DataFrame.assign(z=1, a=1)` will add columns in alphabetical order - i.e. first `a` will be added to existing columns and then `z`.

Comment: It's worth noting that eg. `df = df.assign(c='some_value', b='some_value')` does add the columns in alphabetical order to the original dataframe. So resulting dataframe will have columns a b c and not a c b.

Comment: @Cpt_Jauchefuerst, good point, thank you! I've added it to the answer

Answer (score 4):

A `pd.concat` approach

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=range5))

pd.concat([df.a] * 5, axis=1, keys=list('abcde'))

   a  b  c  d  e
0  0  0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4  4  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you can use a loop to do this:

```
for i in ['b','c']: df[i] = df.a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set them individually if you're only dealing with a few columns:

```
df['b'] = df['a']
df['c'] = df['a']
```

or you can use a loop as you discovered.

Comment: This is what I was hoping to avoid, since in reality I need to add many more columns.

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn't sure from the original question how big of a scope was needed