# Compare two dataframes, add missing columns and populate with zeros

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes df1 and df2. I need to find a union of columns of both and append the missing columns in both of them with zeros
suppose we have two dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({'c1':[0,0,1],'c2':[1,0,0],'c3':[0,6,0]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'c2':[0,0,5],'c4':[1,5,0],'c5':[2,4,2]})
```

then the result should be

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'c1':[0,0,1],'c2':[1,0,0],'c3':[0,6,0],'c4':[0,0,0],'c5':[0,0,0]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'c1':[0,0,0],'c2':[0,0,5],'c3':[0,0,0],'c4':[1,5,0],'c5':[2,4,2]})
```

Comment: The question shows no effort to solve the issue. Always provide a [mre] with **code, data, errors, current & expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)** & **you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and show your effort**.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56907742/7758804) in the duplicate is the same as the answer below.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney In another answer we use 3 dataframes and here only 2. These questions are similar but not duplicates.

Comment: @MykolaZotko that's irrelevant. In the same way there doesn't need to be separate questions to `concat` 4 dataframes compared to 2 dataframes, there doesn't need to be a question for every number of dataframes here. Therefore, you erroneously reopened the question. This is a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46335121/7758804)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the columns [`union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
cols = df1.columns.union(df2.columns)

df1 = df1.reindex(cols, axis=1, fill_value=0)
df2 = df2.reindex(cols, axis=1, fill_value=0)
```

output:

```
# df1
   c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
0   0   1   0   0   0
1   0   0   6   0   0
2   1   0   0   0   0

# df2
   c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
0   0   0   0   1   2
1   0   0   0   5   4
2   0   5   0   0   2
```