# How to add multiple columns to dataframe by function

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, multiple-columns

If I have a df such as this:

```
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

I can use `df['c'] = ''` and `df['d'] = -1` to add 2 columns and become this:

```
   a  b c  d
0  1  3   -1
1  2  4   -1
```

How can I make the code within a function, so I can apply that function to df and add all the columns at once, instead of adding them one by one seperately as above? Thanks

Comment: do you know all the values that correspond to the column names? I'm wondering why you may want to do this.

Comment: @MattR The values are either n/a, or with a bool value, just a default value. Because I want to create a function specifically for adding columns. But I have no idea how to do that for dataframe.

Comment: `df = df.assign(**{'c':1,'d':2})` - or `df.assign(c=1,d=2)` ... https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html?highlight=assign

Comment: Sorry, I want to create a function so it can be used to add columns for different dfs. Is that a way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding multiple columns to pandas simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050539/adding-multiple-columns-to-pandas-simultaneously)

Comment: Make a function that takes a DataFrame and a dictionary as arguments; in the function add the new columns; return the new DataFrame.

Comment: Could you provide some more context for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dictionary:

```
dictionary= { 'c':'', 'd':-1 }

def new_columns(df, dictionary):
    return df.assign(**dictionary)
```

then call it with your df:

```
df = new_columns(df, dictionary)
```

or just ( if you don't need a function call, not sure what your use case is) :

```
df.assign(**dictionary)
```

Comment: why we need a function here ? df.assign(**dictionary)?

Comment: OP wants a function, so that's why i answered with one

Comment: assign is a function itself

Answer (score 0):

```
def update_df(a_df, new_cols_names, new_cols_vals):
  for n, v in zip(new_cols_names, new_cols_vals):
    a_df[n] = v

update_df(df, ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['', 5, 6])
```