# Better way to add the result of apply (multiple outputs) to an existing DataFrame with column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am applying a function on the rows of a dataframe in pandas. That function returns four values (meaning, four values per row). In practice, this means that the returned object from the apply function is a Series containing tuples. I want to add these to their own columns. I know that I can convert that output to a DataFrame and then concatenate with the old DataFrame, like so:

```py
import pandas as pd


def some_func(i):
    return i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4

df = pd.DataFrame(range(10), columns=['start'])
res = df.apply(lambda row: some_func(row['start']), axis=1)

# convert to df and add column names
res_df = res.apply(pd.Series)
res_df.columns = ['label_1', 'label_2', 'label_3', 'label_4']

# concatenate with old df
df = pd.concat([df, res_df], axis=1)
print(df)
```

My question is whether there is a better way to do this? Especially the `res.apply(pd.Series)` seems redundant, but I don't know a better alternative. Performance is an important factor for me.

---

As requested, an example input DataFrame could look like this

```
   start
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6      6
7      7
8      8
9      9
```

And the expected output, with the four added columns:

```
   start  label_1  label_2  label_3  label_4
0      0        1        2        3        4
1      1        2        3        4        5
2      2        3        4        5        6
3      3        4        5        6        7
4      4        5        6        7        8
5      5        6        7        8        9
6      6        7        8        9       10
7      7        8        9       10       11
8      8        9       10       11       12
9      9       10       11       12       13
```

Comment: sample initial dataframe and expected output could be helpful

Comment: @sammywemmy Well, the code is a MCVE so you can just run it. But I've added the example data to give you a visual idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Directly assigning values to the DataFrame would be faster than the concating.

This is one of the way to assign

```
df = pd.DataFrame(range(10), columns=['start'])

df['label_1'], df['label_2'], df['label_3'], df['label_4'] = zip(*[some_func(x) for x in df['start']])
```

This is faster than `res.apply(pd.Series)`.

Refer [adding multiple columns to pandas simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050539/adding-multiple-columns-to-pandas-simultaneously) for more ways to assign multiple columns.

Comment: this is the fastest solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of things to try, instead of `apply` method twice, use a generator and the `pandas.DataFrame` constructor, and the `DataFrame.join` method:

```
import pandas as pd

def some_func(i):
    return i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4

df = pd.DataFrame(range(10), columns=['start'])

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(some_func(x) for x in df['start'])
             .rename(columns=lambda x: f'label_{x+1}'))
```

[out]

```
   start  label_1  label_2  label_3  label_4
0      0        1        2        3        4
1      1        2        3        4        5
2      2        3        4        5        6
3      3        4        5        6        7
4      4        5        6        7        8
5      5        6        7        8        9
6      6        7        8        9       10
7      7        8        9       10       11
8      8        9       10       11       12
9      9       10       11       12       13
```

---

#### Timings

This should offer `~144x` speedup

Using `df = df = pd.DataFrame(range(100000), columns=['start'])` for testing.

original method:

```
22.2 s ± 246 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

this solution:

```
152 ms ± 3.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

@Andrea solution:

```
1.66 s ± 17.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

@Keval Dave solution: **<- fastest!** `~230 x` speedup

```
95.2 ms ± 857 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Could you test mine as well? I suspect `join` might be faster

Comment: `1.61 s ± 46.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` - still a significant speedup :)

Comment: Yep, indeed. I tested it as well. Btw it seems that @Keval Dave method is even faster

Comment: Not sure if it matters for timing, but you didn't test all implementations with the same number of loops. Otherwise, a great answer. Thanks!

Comment: I notice something strange. If I test the timing using `%%time` (just one run) I get that the @Chris A version is consistently faster then @Keval Dave solution. Can you replicate that behavior?

Comment: I'm re-running with 10 loops for all solutions, will update timings - still seeing Keval's as the fastest though

Comment: I'm actually quite surprised that a "non-pandas" approach (by Keval Dave) works fastest. I know it's not fair to call it a non-pandas approach, but I had expected some kind of pandas built-in that did this, but apparently a straightforward Python approach is even better. That's nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a one-liner you can try with:

```
df[['label_1', 'label_2', 'label_3', 'label_4']] = pd.DataFrame(
    df.apply(lambda row: some_func(row['start']), axis=1).tolist())
```

This seems to be a very fast method as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0):

If you return a `pd.Series` from your function, then Pandas will turn its elements into columns of the resulting DataFrame when calling `apply()`.

If you use an index for the Series, the elements in the index will become the names of the columns of the resulting DataFrame.

In your case:

```
res_index = pd.Index([
    'label_1',
    'label_2',
    'label_3',
    'label_4',
])
res_df = df.apply(
    lambda row: pd.Series(some_func(row['start']), index=res_index),
    axis=1,
)
df = pd.concat([df, res_df], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Perhaps slightly cleaner for `res_df` is to apply it to the series only:

```
res_df = df['start'].apply(
    lambda i: pd.Series(some_func(i), index=res_index),
)
```

If you're willing to rewrite your `some_func` to return a `pd.Series` directly:

```
def some_func(i, index=None):
    return pd.Series(
        [i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4],
        index=index,
    )

res_index = pd.Index([
    'label_1',
    'label_2',
    'label_3',
    'label_4',
])
res_df = df['start'].apply(some_func, index=res_index)
df = pd.concat([df, res_df], axis=1)
print(df)
```

All of the above will return the expected result:

```
   start  label_1  label_2  label_3  label_4
0      0        1        2        3        4
1      1        2        3        4        5
2      2        3        4        5        6
3      3        4        5        6        7
4      4        5        6        7        8
5      5        6        7        8        9
6      6        7        8        9       10
7      7        8        9       10       11
8      8        9       10       11       12
9      9       10       11       12       13
```

Comment: Looks like this won't be much faster than the original, since creating one Series per row will still be the bottleneck. Quite often `zip()` really takes the crown!