# Pandas mean method with object type become NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a problem when I try to calculate the mean,my data types is object.
[image]
when im trying this code to get a mean,all i got is NaN value in my kurs_tengah column.

```
df['kurs_tengah'] = df[['kurs_jual','kurs_beli']].mean()
```

heres the data
[image]

what did i do wrong?please tell me!
thank you in advance

Comment: 1) You can't really do `mean` on object type. 2) the right hand side `df[['kurs_jual','kurs_beli']].mean()` is a series indexed by `'kurs_jual','kurs_beli'` which is most likely different from that of `df`.

Comment: thank you,before im trying to convert object to float but i still get the same result.can you give me a solution?

Comment: Can you provide some data from your `dataframe` in question ? @adindaaulia if your `'kurs_jual'`,`'kurs_beli'` is currently as `object type` (and it actually is numbers) then simply typecast it to number type and then apply mean method.

Comment: okay!please check it out

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting a series with 2 mean column values, consider assigning to 2 columns like new_col1, new_col2 below. Also convert the right hand side into list, like -

```
df[['new_col1', 'new_col2']] = df[["kurs_jual", "kurs_beli"]].mean().to_list()
```

Comment: thank you but i got this error "None of [Index(['new_col1', 'new_col2'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Can you paste the code you executed that resulted in this error?

Comment: df[['new_col1', 'new_col2']] = df[["kurs_jual", "kurs_beli"]].mean().to_list(),i just follow ur instruction..sorry if im wrong

Comment: @adinda, try this method as below for individual column assignments -  
df['new_col1'], df['new_col2'] = df[["kurs_jual", "kurs_beli"]].mean().to_list()

There are various approaches to handle multiple column assignments from a list, you can find more details here - 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050539/how-to-add-multiple-columns-to-pandas-dataframe-in-one-assignment