# How to change multiple existing data frame values ​to nan

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I want to change the existing dataframe value to nan. What is the way to do it when you need to change several?

```
dataframe['A', 'B'....] = np.nan
```

I tried this but nothing changed

Comment: Post a sample dataframe and desired output. Also include what have you tried.

Comment: try double brackets dataframe[['A', 'B'....]] = np.nan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add multiple columns to pandas dataframe in one assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050539/how-to-add-multiple-columns-to-pandas-dataframe-in-one-assignment)

Answer (score 0):

Double brackets are required in this case, to pass the list of columns to the dataframe index operator []. For the OP case would be:

```
dataframe[['A', 'B'....]] = np.nan
```

Reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd   

dict= {'ColA':[1,2,3], 'ColB':[4,5,6], 'ColC':[7,8,9], 'ColD':[-1,-2,-3] }    
    
df=pd.DataFrame(dict,index=['I1','I2','I3'])    
print(df) 

df[['ColA','ColD']]=np.nan
print(df)
```

Note:
This solution was originally suggested via comment, now included as an answer with a reproducible example for future reference.