# How to transpose a column in a pandas dataframe with its values drawn from a different column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a pandas dataframe with column "Code" (categorical) with more than 100 unique values. I have multiple rows for same "Name" and would like to capture all of information pertaining to a unique "Name" in one row. Therefore, I'd like to transpose the column "Code" with the values from "Counter".
How do I transpose "Code" in such a way that the following table:

| Name | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Code | Counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice |  |  |  | a1 | 4 |
| Alice |  |  |  | a2 | 3 |
| Bob |  |  |  | b1 | 9 |
| Bob |  |  |  | c2 | 1 |
| Bob |  |  |  | a2 | 4 |

becomes this:

| Name | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | a1 | a2 | b1 | c2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice |  |  |  | 4 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| Bob |  |  |  | 0 | 4 | 9 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

try

`df.pivot(index='Name', columns='Code', values='Counter').fillna(0)`

output

```
Code    a1   a2   b1   c2
Name                     
Alice  4.0  3.0  0.0  0.0
Bob    0.0  4.0  9.0  1.0
```

Comment: This is a sample table, but in reality, I have n number of columns that I want to include in the new data frame. I'd like the result to be a dataframe. How can I do that?

Comment: the answers are based on your question. Your original question is answered, if you need the answer for a more complex question then work on your question so people can answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet but the above answer (from Yuca) should work for you - you can assign the pivot table to a variable and it will be your dataframe. you can also to be sure use Pandas to make it a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
Pivoted = df.pivot(index='Name', columns='Code', values='Counter').fillna(0)

dataframe = pd.Dataframe (data = Pivoted)
```

Comment: how do I add multiple columns to the dataframe? The index only gives one "Name"?

Comment: a simple search on stackoverflow gives you multiple options. here is one that will help, if this answers your question please check mark this answer to close the question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050539/how-to-add-multiple-columns-to-pandas-dataframe-in-one-assignment -